# Problems with changing content of youtube video iframe player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

When I'm trying to access to iframe `getElementById('video');` it returns undefined and I have tried many methods of accessing to iframe content but nothing works. I want change the playlist styles.
Pls help!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: If you need to exercise basic control over the player, try using the [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Comment: For more help, please post what you're trying to do, not just the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't edit the HTML of an iframe that comes from a different domain.

This comes from the cross-domain policy. [More info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

If you still want to do it, you have to be able to run scripts on `iframe` page, <strike>which is not possible for YouTube. (AFAIK)</strike> *Edit:* Didn't know about the [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) as mentioned by John Ellmore.